# Iphone QTVR (QuickTime Virtual Reality) support

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm planning to write iPhone app which have to be able to play QTVR (QuickTime Virtual Reality) movies (it'll be one of its core features). I know there are couple of apps capable of doing it, thus I'm wondering if there is any library available that supports playing such content?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pangeasoft.net/pano/pangeavr/index.html